# Total possible solutions for 8 Queen.

Tags: combinations, permutation, n-queens

Was reading about the 8-Queen problem here - http://en.literateprograms.org/Eight_queens_puzzle_%28C%29

It says 'For eight queens, this solution considers 64^8 or 281474976710656 different solutions'.

Since every consecutive queen will have one less position to consider during its placement on the board, shouldn't that total number of solutions be - (64-1)*(64-2)...(64-8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, they put  "two queens occupy the same square" into consideration. Although 64^8 seem more than yours. The valid solution is the same.

Answer (score 1):

64^8 is true only if you "consider" the possibility of 2 or more queens occupying the same position; which shouldn't be the case.

Your proposed answer of `(64-1)*(64-2)...(64-8)` is essentially:

```
`P(64,8) = 64!/8! = 178462987637760 (permutation)
```

But this presumes that the order in which the queens are placed matters. In reality, it is not important which queen occupies which place, as all 8 queens are considered equivalent and just need to be allotted a position.

So it is more appropriate here to make use of combination (rather than permutation). So the answer would be:

```
C(64,8) = 64!/[(64-8)!x(8!)] = 4426165368
```